# Deleting pointer from DLL

Tags: c++, dll, memory-leaks

ALL,

I have a following issue:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base();
    virtual ~Base();
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1();
    virtual Derived1();
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived2();
    virtual Derived2();
};
```

The base class defined in the DLL, which is statically linked and each child is defined in its own DLL which is loaded on demand.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    ~Foo();
    void CreateObject();
    void SetPointer(Base *base) { m_p = base; };
private:
    void *m_p;
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
    delete m_p;
    m_p = NULL;
}

extern "C" void CreateObject()
{
     Base *base = NULL;
     Foo *foo = new Foo();
     foo->CreateObject( base );
     foo->SetBase( base );
     delete foo;
}

void Foo::CreateObject(Base *m_p)
{
    if( <cond1> )
        m_p = new Derived1();
    if( <cond2> )
        m_p = new Derived2();
}
```

Running this code I am getting memory leak. Running thru the debugger, I see that destructor for Derived1 class is never called.

How do I possibly fix it? The destructors are virtuals and should be called. The only issue is that memory allocation is happening inside a DLL but destructor is called inside the main application.

Is it possible to fix a memory leak or I will have to rethink the design?

Thank you.

Comment: Stop using `new` and `delete`. Use containers and/or smart pointers from the C++ Standard Library or from Boost.

Comment: FYI trying to do allocation and deallocation across DLL boundaries is very risky. You have to guarantee that every piece of code that allocates and deallocates is linked against the exact same runtime libraries. If there is a mismatch, it may crash your process.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious You know containers and smart pointers across DLL boundaries are even dodgier than `new`/`delete` across DLL boundaries, right?

Comment: @immibis It's the developer that's dodgy not the technique. If you have the luxury of using a compatible DLL collection then you avoid the problems. If you don't have a compatible DLL collection you have custom deleters for smart pointers and custom allocators for containers.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious If you don't have a compatible DLL collection (i.e. all DLLs compiled with the same version of the same compiler), **then you cannot pass containers or smart pointers across DLL boundaries, full stop**.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're trying to implement a plugin system so this answer is going to try and sketch out how you'd build such a thing and some of the pitfalls that come to mind.

C++ and DLLs have some interesting challenges associated with them.  For example, extreme care must be taken with:

- allocation and deallocation ('new' and 'delete') of objects passed between DLLs
- throwing and catching exceptions between DLLs
- passing STL objects across DLL boundaries
- function overloading

The approach I've most experience with here is to carefully define the functions exported from a DLL, mark then extern "C", avoid overloading them, and to never throw exceptions from these functions.

Although MSVC does support exportable classes, I'd recommend avoiding them since you'll likely quickly run into the problem areas listed above.

Anyway, one thing that you can relatively safely rely on is sharing interface classes between DLLs.  Interface classes are classes that only contain pure virtual methods.  So for example:

```
class Plugin
{
public:
    virtual void DoFoo() = 0;
    virtual void DoBar() = 0;
};
```

We put Plugin's declaration in a header file that can be included by the application as well as the implementation of the plugin DLLs.

Note that nothing has been dllexported yet.  We're only going to dllexport C-style functions.  By convention, we'll say that our plugin DLLs must provide a "CreatePlugin" function.  Here's an example one:

```
class FirstPlugin : public Plugin
{
public:
    virtual void DoFoo() { std::cout << "FirstPlugin says FOO!\n"; }
    virtual void DoBar() { std::cout << "FirstPlugin says BAR!\n"; }
};

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) Plugin* CreatePlugin()
    {
        return new FirstPlugin();
    }
}
```

And the application that loads the dll can do this:

```
typedef Plugin* (*CreatePluginFn)();
HMODULE module = LoadLibrary("first.dll");

CreatePluginFn createPlugin = (CreatePluginFn)GetProcAddress(module, "CreatePlugin");

Plugin* plugin = createPlugin();
plugin->DoFoo();
plugin->DoBar();
```

I've omitted the necessary FreeLibrary call.  More interesting though is how we deal with freeing up the plugin we created.  The application doesn't necessarily know how CreatePlugin allocated the Plugin instance, so it isn't safe for the application to "delete plugin".  Instead, we need to tell the plugin DLL itself that we're done with it.

The most obvious way to do this would be to add a "Destroy" method to Plugin:

```
class Plugin
{
public:
    virtual void Destroy() = 0;
    virtual void DoFoo() = 0;
    virtual void DoBar() = 0;
};
```

And a possible implementation of this would be:

```
class FirstPlugin : public Plugin
{
public:
    virtual void Destroy() { delete this; }
    virtual void DoFoo() { std::cout << "FirstPlugin says FOO!\n"; }
    virtual void DoBar() { std::cout << "FirstPlugin says BAR!\n"; }
};
```

So now the caller does:

```
plugin->Destroy();
plugin = NULL; // we mustn't use plugin after we're destroyed it!
```

I think that this covers the basics.  It turns out that when you build a lot of code like this that there are common patterns such as:

- using reference counting rather than a big-hammer Destroy method
- interface discovery (like asking a plugin "can you do Foo too?")
- supporting many multiple "CreatePlugin" style functions in a DLL

There are existing solutions to these (eg COM) that may be interesting to look at.

Comment: the only trouble is: the interface between Derived1 and Derived2 are a little different. Imagine you have to work with SQLite and ODBC. You don't want the SQLite library to be dependant on the ODBC, but that's what will happen, right? Because everything is pure virtual. Also in this caseI believe the main application will depend on the Plugin/Base library - I allocate at one place and destroy when the app ends. Now I didn't try it but I think that's what happens. Let me try this approach and I will get back to you. However, I will have to drop pure virtual as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

Allocating in one DLL and deallocating in another is something that can be made to work, but is tricky.  However, I think that you'd see this issue even if all the code was in the same DLL:

In class Foo, the pointer to Base is stored in a void*.  This has the result that the compiler "forgets" that m_p is a Base* instance, and so it just frees the memory without calling the destructor.

Making m_p a Base* should resolve this.

Comment: thank you. I'm changing the code now. Lets see if it works.

Comment: it will not work. It will create a dependancy on the static DLL (the one which have Base) on the main program - exactly what I'm trying to avoid here, The static library should be linked only to 2 DLLs with derived classes. I also can't put Base declaration inside main application - there will be no way for a DLL to get access to this class from the main application. Any idea on how to resolve it nicely?

Comment: I'm sure what you mean by a 'static dll'.  You can share headers between the app and the dlls.  This is quite a standard thing to do.

Comment: Btw,what compiler are you using? I might try and write a more complete answer, but don't want to recommend any language features not supported by your compiler. VC2015?

Comment: by "static DLL", I mean the DLL that exports the class and can be linked to the application. Dynamic DLL on the other hand is something that can be loaded on demand, execute some function from it and then unloaded. About compiler - I'm using MSVC 2010.

Comment: Eek - not sure I can remember as far back as 2010!  Not tempted to upgrade to 2015 so you can use more modern C++?

Comment: For the concern about Foo taking a dependency on the Base - it already has one in the SetPointer method.  I think that there's some misconceptions about what actually gets exported from a DLL that I'll try and address in another answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100727/discussion-between-damyan-and-igor).